# Confusion about Product Topology and a counter example, if possible

Tags: general-topology

I need help understanding Product Topology and it seems like I need to write down my ideas correctly:

In Section 15 of Munkres' Topology, I learned that if $\,U\,$ is open in a topological space $X$, and if $\, V\,$ is open in a topological space $Y$, then $\,U\times V\,$ is a basis element of the topology on $\,X\times Y\,$ *but it is not necessarily open* in $\,X\times Y\,$ (Munkres explains it in the 4th paragraph of that section using Fig 15.1).

**(1)** Is there *another* example to see the "not necessarily open" part? That is, something open in $X$ and open in $Y$ but not open in $X\times Y$?

On the other hand, if $W$ is open in $X\times Y$, then $W$ can be written as $W = \underset{\alpha,\beta}\cup (B_\alpha\times C_\beta)$ where $B_\alpha$ and $C_\beta$ are basis elements of the topology on $X$ and $Y$, respectively. However, $\underset{\alpha,\beta}\cup (B_\alpha\times C_\beta) = (\underset{\alpha}\cup B_\alpha)\times (\underset{\beta}\cup C_\beta) = P\times Q$.

**(2)** Therefore, can we always write an open set in $X\times Y$, say $W$, as a product of open sets in $X$ and $Y$, like $W = P \times Q$?

Comment: Let's imagine $2$ concentric circles on plane and set between them.

Comment: I think your description of Munkres is wrong.  I would say: $U \times V$ is a basis element of the topology on $X \times Y$, and therefore $U \times V$ is open.  But not every open set in $X \times Y$ has the form $U \times V$.

Comment: Thanks, @GEdgar, is there an example (apart from circles and rectangles), say in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to see this?

Comment: @GEdgar, is my description of point #2, correct?

Comment: The answer to (2) is "no".

Comment: Oh my God! Can you please help me where I am wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (1) the description is incorrect.  An open set $W$ can be written in the form $W = \bigcup_\alpha(B_\alpha \times C_\alpha)$.  Usually, it cannot be written in the form $W = \bigcup_{\alpha,\beta}(B_\alpha \times C_\beta)$

In $\mathbb R^2$ consider something like $(0,1)^2 \cup (4,5)^2$, the union of two squares.  It is open, since it is the union of two of the basic open sets, but it is not itself of the form $U \times V$.

More generally, take a (finite or infinite) union of basic open sets; except in very rare cases, that union will not be of the form $U \times V$.

As an exercise, show that the set $\{(x,y) : x < y\}$ is an open set by showing it is an infinite union of basic open sets.

Comment: Thank you so much, @GEdgar. I see, that makes sense. Here is one thing I find very hard to understand when Munkres discusses Projections on page 87 of his Topology book: 

If $U$ is an open subset of $X$, then the set $\pi_1^{-1}(U)$ is precisely the set $U\times Y$, which is open in $X\times Y$. Why is the latter true then? It seems like the claim being made is the following: If $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$, then the sets $U\times Y$ and $X\times V$ are both open in $X\times Y$ - how does one understand this?

Comment: $U \times Y$ is open in $X \times Y$ because of two things:  $U$ is open in $X$ and $Y$ is open in $Y$.  For a topological space, the whole space is an open set.